# Main Terminal Window Displaying Commands Only

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I often lose track of the command flow due to the long text output of some commands, so I would like to have a **main terminal window** where user commands are executed and **other terminal windows** that „pop up“ displaying the commands' output and then are closed with the use of a short-cut.

Is it possible to code such a behavior? Any tips about the language I should use?

An even more user-friendly interaction would be for the terminal to **ask** whether it should display the output externally if it exceeds a user-set limit.

Comment: The easiest way might be to pipe the output into `less`, i.e. type `MYCOMMAND | less` if you run a command from which you expect long output. That way the output will be visible in a scrollable pager which you exit by pressing the `Q` key. Once you exit `less`, you're back to the shell and it will look like there was no output at all. It all happens in the same terminal though, no separate windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know little about programming languages, but Bash can definitely set up to behave like you want it, so here's how I would do it.

## General Setup

Define a function in your `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc` file that allows you to start your command in a new terminal, e.g.

```
foo () { ( xterm -hold -e bash -c "$*" & ) ;}
```

This way `foo echo bar` opens up a new `xterm` which shows just the output of `echo bar`, here this would be a window with just the word `bar` in it. A chain of commands must be quoted, e.g. `foo "echo bar && echo baz"`. You can substitute `xterm` by the terminal emulator of your choice, but you need to figure out what the *stay open* option is – read the `man` page. Option `-e` should work for all of them. Note that as a function name you can choose even a single symbol like `:`, `_` or `·` (<kbd>AltR</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>).

#### Explanations

- `foo () { … ;}` – define a function `foo` which does `…`
- `( … )` – start `…` in a subshell, this releases the original terminal so that a new command can be executed even when other output terminals are still open
- `xterm -hold -e …` – run `xterm`, run `…` and `-hold` it open after the command finished
- `bash -c " … "` – execute the command(s) `…`, needed for being able to run multiple commands
- `$*` – matches every argument of `foo` = the full chain of commands after `foo`

## Fine-tuning

### Closing the output terminal window

You can close the output terminal using your desktop environment's standard shortcut for that – <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> by default.

If you want the output terminal to stay open for let's say five seconds **after** the command finished, you need to define the function like so:

```
foo () { ( xterm -e bash -c "$* && sleep 5" & ) ;}
```

Replace `&&` by `&` for the terminal to stay open only until the command is finished, but **at least** five seconds.

### Input facilitation

#### Using `xdotool` (ugly and dirty, *boo*)

It'll bother you to type `foo` before every single command in your main terminal, so I set up a dirty workaround for that – install `xdotool` first if necessary. When you open your main terminal, first set this variable:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='xdotool type "foo "'
```

This will automatically type `foo` followed by a space after, but unfortunately also before every new prompt. All left for you to do is to type your (chain of) command(s).

#### Using a `perl` function (massively cool)

*The question how to perform the following was asked on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391679) and got a brilliant answer by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas), whose solution is used here. If this helps you in any way please visit the linked question and upvote his answer.*

Add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc` file and save it:

```
insert() { perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph"; ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV' -- "$@" ;}
auto_enter() { bind $'"\u200b":"\1'$1' \5"'; PROMPT_COMMAND="insert $'\u200b'" ;}
```

Now when you open a new terminal and run `auto_enter foo`, the string “foo ” (with the space automatically added) will appear after every new prompt. If you type something while a command is executed, “foo ” is going to be inserted even before this text.

### User-friendly interaction

This version of the function saves the output in a temp file, counts its lines and asks the user whether to display it in a new window:

```
foo () {
  limit=10 # set line limit
  tf=$(mktemp) # create temp file
  "$@" > $tf # execute command, save output in temp file
  lc=$(wc -l < $tf) # get output's line count
  [ $lc -ge $limit ] && # if line count >= limit then
  ( read -p "The output is $lc lines long, do you want to open it in a new window (y/n)? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) xterm -hold -e "cat $tf" & exit;; # open in new window, send to background and exit
        [Nn]* ) cat $tf; exit;; # print output to stdout and exit
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";; # wrong answer
    esac ) || # else
  cat $tf # print output to stdout
}
```

Of course this can be highly tweaked and customized, but I think it's a good start.

## And Now for Something Completely Different™

A totally different way of achieving your goal is using shell output redirection. `who` gives you a list of running terminals, e.g.:

```
> who
username tty7         2017-09-07 20:46 (:0)
username pts/2        2017-09-07 20:47 (:0)
username pts/1        2017-09-07 21:05 (:0)
```

You can send the output to any of them by simply appending e.g. `> /dev/pts/1` to your command, which of course can also be used in a function as shown above.

GNOME Terminal emulator (`gnome-terminal`) sessions are not displayed by `who`, nonetheless the `pts` devices exist equally for them. You can determine open terminal sessions just by trying or with `ls /dev/pts | sed '/^[0p]/d'` instead.

Comment: No matter how many new terminals I open, `who` gives me only username tty7

Comment: I use the GNOME Terminal emulator. Installed by default on my Ubuntu.

Comment: It works with xterm. I get the running terminals list after `who`.

Comment: You don't know how *much* I enjoyed working this out…

Comment: Thanks @dessert - this (redirection) will come in very handy! I'm on Kubuntu 17.10, but I have gnome-terminal installed (as well as Kubuntu's default Konsole). Works great in Konsole, strange it doesn't work in gnome-terminal.

Comment: @dessert - very cool tip, thanks! Works very well with terminals where you can have a split screen, like KDE's Konsole: http://img.ctrlv.in/img/17/09/09/59b3e80a09d1f.png